# Is it possible to tweak round corners of UI?

Tags: interface, customization

I haven't seen an option which allow to "rectangularize" some rounded corners of UI buttons. It is possible ?

[image: rounded cornerz]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not yet,
but I dislike the rounded corners as well, I decided to fix this.
It's hardcoded, so I'm exposing a option that enables you to turn this on\off.

I've uploaded a patch here:
https://developer.blender.org/D2178

I have a example screenshot here showing it:

[image: screenshot]